# How to know when to update my facebook profile pic from cache?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

In my app, am caching facebook profile pics in sdcard (for caching) with filenames stored as URL link "**http://graph.facebook.com/1146636239/picture**"  --> Something like this.

Whenever i look for download for the profile image, i check in sdcard and pull up the image.

Suppose if my friend has changed his profile pic, how will i know to download the new updated image ? (rather than picking from sdcard.)

Is there any api to know if profile pic has changed wrt to a time stamp ?

Any insights would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Does any one worked on facebook profile picture caching on client side ?